# Android Facebook SDK, requesting publish permission "manage_pages" isn't updating session permissions list

Tags: java, android, facebook, parse-platform

I am using Parse and Facebook SDKs on Android. I'm trying to request for the permission "manage_pages" after the facebook account is linked. But whenever I make the request it does NOT add to the list of permissions in `Session.getPermissions()`. However, the Facebook dialog popup asking for the "manage_pages" permission appears, and it is listed in my Facebook Apps settings on facebook.com.

In MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Receiving activity result with requestCode: " + requestCode + " resultcode: " + resultCode);
    if (requestCode == 32665) // Code for when facebook is NOT linked
        ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication(requestCode, resultCode,
                data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In FacebookFragment's `onCreateView()`:

```
        connectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (user == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User is null.");
                    return;
                }
                if (!ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
                    ParseFacebookUtils.link(user,
                            FacebookFragment.this.getActivity(),
                            new SaveCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException ex) {
                                    if (ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
                                        Log.d(TAG,
                                                "Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
                                        user.add(ParseConstants.USER_ARRAY_NETWORKS, ParseConstants.NETWORK_CODE_FACEBOOK);
                                        user.saveInBackground();

                                        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                                        // Check for publish permissions
                                        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
                                        if (!permissions
                                                .contains(Permissions.Page.MANAGE_PAGES)) {
                                            Log.e(TAG, "We don't have hte permission: " + Permissions.Page.MANAGE_PAGES + "... we have " + Arrays.toString(permissions.toArray()));
                                            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                                                    getActivity(),
                                                    "manage_pages");
                                            newPermissionsRequest.setRequestCode(23232);
                                            newPermissionsRequest.setCallback(new StatusCallback() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void call(
                                                        Session session,
                                                        SessionState state,
                                                        Exception exception) {
                                                    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();

                                                    Log.e(TAG, "CALLBACK Permissions: " + Arrays.toString(permissions.toArray()));
                                                    if (exception != null)
                                                        Log.e(TAG, "EXCEPTION: " + exception.getMessage());
                                                }

                                            });
                                            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
//                                          ParseFacebookUtils.saveLatestSessionData(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                                        }

                                        showMessages();
                                    } else {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "Uhh user is not linked");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                } else
                    Log.e(TAG, "User is already linked!");
            }
        });
```

FacebookFragment's `onStart`:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
        showMessages();


        Session session = ParseFacebookUtils.getSession();
        // Check for publish permissions
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();

        Log.e(TAG, "Permissions: " + Arrays.toString(permissions.toArray()));
        Log.e(TAG, "Permissions: " + Arrays.toString(Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions().toArray()));

    }
}
```

This is what appears in logCat:

> ```
> 05-20 15:55:53.077: E/FacebookFragment(1887): We don't have hte permission: manage_pages... we have [public_profile]
> 05-20 15:55:53.337: E/FacebookFragment(1887): CALLBACK Permissions: []
> 05-20 15:55:54.228: E/MainActivity(1887): Receiving activity result with requestCode: 23232 resultcode: -1
> 05-20 15:55:54.228: E/FacebookFragment(1887): Permissions: [public_profile]
> 05-20 15:55:54.228: E/FacebookFragment(1887): Permissions: [public_profile]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as you, unfortunately the Sessions.getPermissions() is pretty useless, you have to logout and login again in the app for the session object to be updated.
I tried everything.

What I ended up doing was to totally ditch the session.getPermissions() and just make requests online to the **/me/permissions** Graph API.

It's the only reliable one that works, without logging in/logging out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the function `Session.isPublishPermission("manage_pages")`?
I had the same problem as you, but by using this function, it returned a correct `boolean` value.